# How to achieve TRANSITION effect with setInterval method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, css-transitions

I've set up a web page which changes the background color of the body after every 2 seconds. What I've been struggling with is how to integrate **transition** effect into the `setInterval` method. I want the new colors to appear with a fade effect, just like the transition property does in CSS. **How can I achieve this effect for these changing/switching background colors?**

Here's my code:

```js
var startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
var body = document.getElementById("body");

// Click Event Listener
startButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    body.style.backgroundColor = generateRandomColors();
  }, 2000);
});


// GENERATE Random Colors
function generateRandomColors() {
  var arr = [];
  arr.push(pickRandomColor());
  return arr;
}

// PICK Random Color
function pickRandomColor() {
  // Red
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  // Green
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  // Blue
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  // RGB
  var rgb = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
  return rgb;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body id="body">
  <button id="startButton">Start</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of `return arr;` just `return pickRandomColor()`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [transition property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) specifying which property you want to transition and how long it will take.

```js
var startButton = document.getElementById("startButton");
var body = document.getElementById("body");

// Click Event Listener
startButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    body.style.backgroundColor = generateRandomColors();
  }, 2000);
});


// GENERATE Random Colors
function generateRandomColors() {
  var arr = [];
  arr.push(pickRandomColor());
  return arr;
}

// PICK Random Color
function pickRandomColor() {
  // Red
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  // Green
  var g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  // Blue
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
  // RGB
  var rgb = "rgb(" + r + ", " + g + ", " + b + ")";
  return rgb;
}
```

```css
body { transition: background-color 2s; }
```

```html
<html>
<body id="body">
  <button id="startButton">Start</button>
</body>
</html>
```